# establish connection to oracle with Google Apps Script via JDBC

Tags: oracle, google-apps-script

I'm trying to establish the connection to oracle database using Google Apps Script from google sheet by using the sample code below.

But, I keep getting error: Exception: Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol.

// make the connection
var connection = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:oracle://db IP or host name:port number/DB name", "User name", "password");

Comment: According to the Oracle documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html the URL format should be `jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:@<database>`

Though I haven't figured it out myself yet and hoping for some clarity.